# HTML syntax highlighting in javascript strings in vim

Tags: javascript, html, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I don't know if this is possible/sensible, but I was curious to know if I can have my strings in javascript files have html highlighting. I discovered that strings in php could have SQL syntax highlighting, so I believe it is possible.

But, I don't know vim-scripting, so any help on this appreciated.

I am using the [Better Javascript syntax](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491).

PS: If there could be an option to turn it on and off while editing a js file, that would be wonderful

Thanks

Comment: +1, I'd like to be able to do this too... I have a ton of HTML embedded in JS files.

Python embedded in my vimrc is highlighted correctly, so this sort of thing is definitely possible.

Comment: wow! It really does.. I never wrote any python in my vimrc, so never noticed.. lol!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you don't mind some syntax file hacking. First you need to include the HTML syntax file from within the Javascript syntax file -- see `:help syn-include` for info on that; second you need to declare that HTML syntax can be found inside of certain elements (i.e. strings). Third, if you want to have the option of enabling and disabling it, you can make those commands dependent on a global variable, and write some mappings that set or unset the variable and then reload the syntax file.

For examples on how inclusion works, take a look at `syntax/html.vim` (which includes the Javascript and CSS syntax files), `syntax/perl.vim` (which includes the POD syntax file), or `php.vim` (which includes SQL syntax highlighting in strings, conditional on a global ariable).

*Edit: did some work on actually making this happen in my copy*.

In the head of `syntax/javascript.vim`, just below `syn case ignore`, add

```
syn include @javaScriptHTML syntax/html.vim
unlet b:current_syntax
syn spell default " HTML enables spell-checking globally, turn it off
```

Then add `@javaScriptHTML` to the `contained=` lists for `javaScriptStringD` and `javaScriptStringS`.

Finally you have to edit `syntax/html.vim` to prevent it from trying to include `syntax/javascript.vim` if it was loaded *from* javascript: find the line that reads

```
if main_syntax != 'java' || exists("java_javascript")
```

and change it to

```
if main_syntax != 'javascript' && ( main_syntax != 'java' || exists("java_javascript")
```

Comment: so, is it going to be like 'syntax include @javaScriptStringS syntax/html.vim', but if I add that to my javascript.vim, I am not able to see anything when I open a js file... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: somehow i still ended up getting html.vim imported recursively :(

Comment: Thanks hobbs, sorry that I am coming back quite late, but I tried your solution and I did manage to get some html colors in my strings, but there still are 2 problems, all the '>' symbols in the file appear with a red background, like unmatched or something, and the string first opened in the js file, never ends... i.e., the whole file after the first ' is highlighted as a js string... Thanks for the help...