# Trouble using Vim's syn-include and syn-region to embed syntax highlighting

Tags: python, vim, latex, syntax-highlighting, tex

I am trying to get Vim to syntax highlight any file that ends with extension `.Rtex` in the following way:

- All top level text is highlighted as TeX
- Exception: any text enclosed in `\begin{python}...\end{python}` is highlighted as Python

I am able to achieve each of these criteria individually, but unable to achieve both simultaneously. I think that somehow the TeX highlighting overrides my Python-highlighted regions, or prevents them from taking effect, and I am stuck trying to figure out how.

**First step:** edit `.vimrc` to give files with extension `.Rtex` the filetype `rtex`:

```
  au BufRead *.Rtex setf rtex
```

**Second step:** create `~/.vim/syntax/rtex.vim`. It is the contents of this file that will determine how to highlight `.Rtex` files.

**Third step:** enable general top-level TeX highlighting, by making `rtex.vim` look like this:

```
runtime! syntax/tex.vim
```

If I now open a `.Rtex` file, the entire file is highlighted as TeX, including any text within `\begin{python}...\end{python}`, as expected.

**Fourth step:** follow the instructions in Vim's `:help syn-include` to include python highlighting and apply it to all regions delimited by `\begin{python}` and `\end{python}`. My `rtex.vim` file now looks like this:

```
runtime! syntax/tex.vim
unlet! b:current_syntax
syntax include @Python syntax/python.vim
syntax region pythonCode start="\\begin{python}" end="\\end{python}" contains=@Python
```

The `unlet! b:current_syntax` command is meant to force the `python.vim` syntax file to execute even though an existing syntax (TeX) is already active.

**Problem:** If I now open a `.Rtex` file, the entire file is still highlighted only as TeX. The `\begin{python}...\end{python}` region seems to have no effect.

**Experiment:** If I remove or comment out the `runtime!` command, I *do* get python highlighting, within the `\begin{python}...\end{python}` regions, exactly as desired, but of course no TeX highlighting in the remainder of the document. I therefore conclude that the TeX highlighting is somehow responsible for preventing the python regions from taking effect.

Can a Master of Vim offer me any suggestions? I am currently stumped. I have looked at several pages and stackoverflow questions that seem relevant, but none of them have so far led to a solution:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file
- [Embedded syntax highligting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519753/vimembedded-syntax-highligting)
- [VIM syntax highlighting of html nested in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829666/vim-syntax-highlighting-of-html-nested-in-yaml)

Comment: Thanks, and hello from 2022! This question, the references you listed, and your answer helped me write [a syntax file](https://gist.github.com/ernstki/7bf7cef49705324121363133561400c9) for Alpine.js, which highlights JavaScript within specific HTML attributes such as `x-data`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some more study of the manual, and much more trial and error, I have finally answered my own question (a simultaneously embarrassing and sublime accomplishment), which I now preserve here for posterity.

Basically, I think the problem is that the python highlighting wouldn't take effect because the `pythonCode` region was itself contained in a region or highlight group defined by `tex.vim`, so it wasn't top-level. The solution is to also `include` (rather than just `runtime`) `tex.vim`, giving it a name like `@TeX`, and then add `containedin=@TeX` to my python region definition. So `syntax/rtex.vim` now looks like this:

```
let b:current_syntax = ''
unlet b:current_syntax
runtime! syntax/tex.vim

let b:current_syntax = ''
unlet b:current_syntax
syntax include @TeX syntax/tex.vim

let b:current_syntax = ''
unlet b:current_syntax
syntax include @Python syntax/python.vim
syntax region pythonCode matchgroup=Snip start="\\begin{python}" end="\\end{python}" containedin=@TeX contains=@Python

hi link Snip SpecialComment
let b:current_syntax = 'rtex'
```

And this works! I'm not sure if all of those `unlet b:current_syntax` commands are strictly necessary. I also gave the python region delimiters a matchgroup (`Snip`) so that they can be highlighted themselves (with the `SpecialComment` color), rather than left just plain, which is apparently what happens by default, since they are no longer considered part of the TeX.

Now it is a trivial thing to add more highlight regions for different languages (e.g., `\begin{Scode}...\end{Scode}`), which is great if you're getting into literate programming -- the original motivation for my question.

Edit: here is a screenshot showing how it works with Python and R code embedded in a TeX document:
[image: Screenshot: Python and R embedded in TeX]

Comment: Does this lead to LaTex compile time errors since `\begin{Python}` is unknown?

Comment: Nope, notice the `\usepackage{python}` which defines the `python` environment.

Comment: what if I want to use syntax based on `\begin{Puk'sSuperAmazingLanguage}` ? =P

Comment: @puk, you'll need two things: a syntax file for Vim to do the syntax highlighting of this amazing language (`amazinglanguage.vim` or whatever), and you'll need to define the `Puk'sSuperAmazingLanguage` environment for LaTeX, whether there's a package you can use that defines it, or you have to code it yourself, or whatever. What LaTeX actually _does_ with the contents of that environment is also up to you or the package writer.

Comment: @Maxy-B — Do you know if it is possible to also apply auto-indent rules to these Python blocks? It would be awesome if vim would somehow apply all the Python-filetype stuff to code in a {python}-environment; while applying LaTeX-filetype stuff to all the other code. The syntax highlighting is great; but auto-indent would also be really cool.

Comment: Struggling to use your answer, and borrowing from [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519753/embedded-syntax-highligting-in-vim), for reasons I do not comprehend, it was necessary to include the `keepend` between the `start` and `end` definitions; it would not switch back to my "containing" syntax once it got into a region otherwise.... Otherwise, great question and answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but a hack I use with my Rnw files that use both tex and rnoweb features is as follows:

```
 au BufEnter *.Rnw set filetype=tex | set filetype=rnoweb
```

Would an adapted version work in your case?

Comment: Right, so that gives the file both filetypes, causing both highlighters to apply everywhere -- only a partial solution, since I just want python highlighting within certain regions. I didn't know you could use a pipe like that (as opposed to `set filetype=tex.rnoweb`), though, so thanks!

Comment: does the pipe differ from using dot notation like `setfiletype=js.php`?