# Forcing multiple file types in Vim

Tags: vim, file-type

Vim supports [multiple file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601403/multiple-file-types-in-vim) for the main file formats. But this does not work for less popular formats such as LaTex and grapviz. Try it out for yourself, go [here](http://www.duocoding.nl/blog/249/how-to-embed-dot-graphs-graphviz-in-latex), copy paste the code into vim and try setting the file type to any permutation of `.tex` and `.doc` or `.gv`

Is there a way to inform vim that I am entering a different file type block? Something like

```
\author{John Smith}
\title{This is LaTex}

\*!setfiletype .gv!*\
digraph G{...}
\*!setfiletype .tex!*\

This is Latex Again
```

Comment: Ooo! Yes there is, check out having R and Latex in the same file with Sweave, I've seen vim syntax highlighting questions about those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you would need a custom Tex syntax file that includes Graphviz's syntax.

Both `:help syn-include` and this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176972/trouble-using-vims-syn-include-and-syn-region-to-embed-syntax-highlighting) might help.

Or you may do things in a more straightforward fashion: edit Tex stuff in `.tex` files and Graphviz stuff in `.gv` files.