# How do I get VIM to recognize PHP block based on <script language="php">?

Tags: php, vim, syntax-highlighting, indentation

For legacy reasons I'm stuck delimiting PHP code blocks via:

```
<script language="PHP">
```

as opposed to:

```
<?php
```

This is a valid way of opening a PHP block (see ["Escaping from HTML on php.net"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)); the only problem is, that **VIM interprets this as JavaScript**, forcing me to execute `:set ft=php` each time, if I want it to highlight and indent my code according to PHP specific rules.

I could map `:set ft=php` to a shortcut but that's still rather inconvenient. Does anyone know of a way to automate this?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh... and I have my PHP code in files with either the .htm or .php extensions, and in both cases I'm forced to delimit PHP blocks via `<script language="PHP>`. While the syntax highlighting appears to be JavaScript, `:set ft?` reports `"filetype=html"`.

Answer (score 2):

See [narrow](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2097) and [nrrwrgn](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075).

Both scripts allow you to select a "region" of code, edit it in another window with whatever filetype you want and save it back to its original location.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't this be roughly on the same level as having to execute `:set ft=php`? If I understand correctly, using `narrow`, `nrrwrgn` and `:set ft=php` would all result in the desired filetype but they are all manual and would have to be applied for each file... Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: It is the same thing but applied to a region instead of the whole buffer. What you really need are two customized syntax files (one for HTML and one for PHP). I doubt anybody here will take the time and effort to write these for you as it's not a particularly trivial task and probably too specific and rare. In the mean time, you could have a look at `:help syntax` and see if you can adapt your existing syntax files to your need.

Comment: As you suggested, I had a look at my syntax files and realized that I would also have to adjust the indent, code-complete and filetype files making adjustments to both HTML and PHP related files to achieve complete support for `<script language="php">`, which indeed, doesn't appear all that trivial. Given that I have minimal familiarity with VIM script, I think I'll either use the plugins you suggested or manually execute `:set ft=php` for the time being. Bummer.

Comment: May I ask why you use this particular construction? I've been doing PHP on and off for about 6 years and I've never come accross `<script language="php">`. Even in the poor tutorials I've read at the beginning.

Comment: There's an old external tool that we use to edit some pages which has the annoying habit of scanning files and "correcting" HTML files. Unfortunately, it doesn't understand `<?php` and as such goes about deleting those blocks; it does however, leave `<script language="php">` blocks alone; this situation has little to do with poor programming, it's simply legacy. We're in the process of migrating the site to a CMS, which will put an end to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just automate the file to the php filetype you can do `au FileType html set ft=php` if `:set ft?` shows html. Or you can do it by extension like `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.htm set ft=php`

Also, read this: [Different syntax highlighting within regions of a file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I use .php and .htm file extensions and in each case I need to use the `<script language="php">` delimiter (even if the file consists of PHP only).For PHP files, I thought the `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php set ft=php` option you provided might work but where would I place it/when would I execute it? I placed it in my .vimrc file (and restarted VIM) but it made no difference -- :set ft? still reported html when in my .php file and a <script language="php"> block...

Comment: I also looked at the page you referred to but am still trying to figure out how to apply this info for my purposes, especially given how the method provided there supposedly won't work on files that VIM already assigns a filetype to by default. I'm also looking at [VIM syntax highlighting of html nested in yaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829666/vim-syntax-highlighting-of-html-nested-in-yaml) in this context.